# How to add certain number to an objects Z rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I'm trying to make a thing where I have a car and when I'm within a certain area, the wheels turn and I can fly. It works fine, but my car is very front heavy and as soon as I'm in the air, I start spinning forward so I'm trying to add a number to the cars Z rotation, in this case frontLift. I've tried other peoples solutions and none of them have worked. With this I'm getting an error saying "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quaternion' and 'Vector3'".

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Flying : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int wheelAngle = 90;
    public float maxHeight;
    public float rocketPower;

    public Transform[] wheels;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float frontLift;

    void Update()
    {
        float xPos = transform.position.x;
        float yPos = transform.position.y;

        if(xPos > -16 && xPos < 15){
            foreach(Transform wheel in wheels){
                wheel.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
            }
            if(Input.GetKey("space") && yPos < maxHeight){
                rb.AddForce(0, rocketPower, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
                transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation + new Vector3(0, 0, frontLift);
            }
        }
        else{
            foreach(Transform wheel in wheels){
                wheel.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to unity and c# so this is very new to me, and I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add two rotations via the [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html).

Then in order to get a `Quaternion` rotation for an Euler axis you use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) so together it should be

```
transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, frontLift);
```

or in short

```
transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, frontLift);
```

Or you could use [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) in order to rotate around a certain axis like e.g.

```
transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(frontLift, transform.forward);
```

---

**BUT**!

I can see you have a `Rigidbody` here. As soon as there is a `Rigidbody` involved you shouldn't get or set anything via the `Transform` component but rather only via the `Rigidbody` component.

Here you could use e.g. [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)

```
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(frontLift, rb.rotation * Vector3.forward));
```

you would, however, need to do this in `FixedUpdate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply saying that you are adding Quaternion and Vector3.
Unity stores rotations as Quaternions internally. So the following code

```
transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation + new Vector3(0, 0, frontLift);
```

should be

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, frontLift);
```

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html

Comment: how do I make it keep adding this while the key is pressed? I tried putting that in a while(Input.GetKey("space)) loop but all that did was crash unity, even when frontLift was at a super low value